# Python | delimited text file to csv format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python but I'm having trouble reading a text file which contains data separated by "|" as the delimiter. How would I separate the file into columns in a CSV format.

```
import csv
my_file_name = "NVG.txt"
cleaned_file = "cleanNVG.csv"

with open(my_file_name, 'r') as infile, open(cleaned_file, 'w') as outfile:
    data = infile.read()

    data = data.replace("|","")
    outfile.write(data)
```

This code gets rid of the **|** to a blank but all the data is just in one column now. How can I format this correctly?
I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Why are you removing the |? Why don't you just tell `csv` that that is your separator? i.e. `csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) allows you to read csv files with practically arbitrary delimiters.

```
with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile:
    for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|'):
        # do stuff
```

If you really want to reformat the file, you can use the `csv.writer` directly:

```
with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile, open(cleaned_file, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|'):
        writer.writerow(line)
```

---

Note that your approach doesn't work because you *remove* the separator instead of replacing it. `data.replace("|","")` will replace each `|` with the empty string, i.e. `"foo|bar"` becomes `"foobar"`. You must replace the old separator with a *new* one, e.g. `data.replace("|", ",")`.

Comment: Ohh Okay!!! Thanks! The data is now in their columns but it leaves an empty row after. so Row 1 has data and Row 2 is blank , Row 3 has Data and Row 4 is blank and so on.... why is it doing that?

Comment: @Cesar Define the *writer* object as `writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator="\n")`

Comment: Actually never mind, the **newline= ''**was messed up. This worked perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way with your code would be to replace "|" with "," rather than removing "|"

```
data = data.replace("|", ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're importing the `csv` module, but aren't using it. Make use of [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

```
with open(my_file_name, 'r') as infile, open(cleaned_file, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|')
```